# Finding minimum using bit manipulation

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

Can anybody explain to me the following line of code. It is used to find the minimum of two numbers.

```
int min(int x, int y)

{

  return  y + ((x - y) & ((x - y) >>
            (sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT - 1)));

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what's the value of `CHAR_BIT`? Possible 8?

Comment: Well.. it doesn't even work. Consider x = INT_MIN, y = 1

Comment: Very few algorithms work when overflow occurs.

Comment: @Taywee it doesn't fail in a trivial "just because of overflow"-way, it's fundamentally limited, giving it a pre-condition that `min` does not normally have.

Answer (score 5):

> It is used to find the minimum of two numbers.

This code unfortunate fails for many combinations of `int` rendering it of very reduced value.  [@harold](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39195391/finding-minimum-using-bit-manipulation/39197429#comment65731402_39195391)   A good compiler will recognize `x < y ? x: y;` and generate correct and fast code. [@David C. Rankin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39195391/finding-minimum-using-bit-manipulation#comment65732423_39195531)

Determining how it works is not as interesting as how it fails.

1. Undefined behavior: Should `x - y` overflow, the compliant compiler may generate any output - even crash.  Optimizing compilers take advantage of this to the chagrin of new programmers.
2. Shifting the sign bit is implementation defined behavior as with  `some_negative_int >> (sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT - 1)))`.  An arithmetic right shift of an `int` is common, yet not specified by C.
3. `some_int >> (sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT - 1)))` can exceed the maximum allowed shift should `int` contain padding (This is rare).

---

OP's code fails for many combinations of `x,y` - Failed 31 of 121 tests cases - see below.  ["It accomplishes this by an arithmetic shift"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39195479/2410359) is implementation-defined behavior.  The potential overflow of `x-y` is undefined behavior.  Without addressing these, any answer is incomplete.

Corner cases ["it works for any other sizes"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39195531/2410359) is commonly true, yet rare platforms may utilize padding in `int`, rendering the `sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT - 1` problematic.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int minz(int x, int y) {
  return  y + ((x - y) & ((x - y) >> (sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT - 1)));
}

void testmin(int x, int y) {
  static unsigned count = 0;
  static unsigned fail = 0;
  int min0 = x < y ? x: y;
  int min1 = minz(x,y);
  count++;
  if (min0 != min1) {
    fail++;
    printf("%u/%u min(%d, %d)--> %d, should be %d\n", fail,count, x,y, min1, min0);
  }
}
int main(void) {
  const int i[]={INT_MIN, INT_MIN+1, INT_MIN+2, -2,-1,0, 1, 2, INT_MAX-2,INT_MAX-1, INT_MAX};
  int x,y;
  for (x=0; x<sizeof i/sizeof i[0]; x++) {
    for (y=0; y<sizeof i/sizeof i[0]; y++) {
      testmin(i[x],i[y]);
    }
  }
}
```

Output (Failures)

```
1/7 min(-2147483648, 1)--> 1, should be -2147483648
2/8 min(-2147483648, 2)--> 2, should be -2147483648
3/9 min(-2147483648, 2147483645)--> 2147483645, should be -2147483648
4/10 min(-2147483648, 2147483646)--> 2147483646, should be -2147483648
5/11 min(-2147483648, 2147483647)--> 2147483647, should be -2147483648
6/19 min(-2147483647, 2)--> 2, should be -2147483647
7/20 min(-2147483647, 2147483645)--> 2147483645, should be -2147483647
8/21 min(-2147483647, 2147483646)--> 2147483646, should be -2147483647
9/22 min(-2147483647, 2147483647)--> 2147483647, should be -2147483647
10/31 min(-2147483646, 2147483645)--> 2147483645, should be -2147483646
11/32 min(-2147483646, 2147483646)--> 2147483646, should be -2147483646
12/33 min(-2147483646, 2147483647)--> 2147483647, should be -2147483646
13/44 min(-2, 2147483647)--> 2147483647, should be -2
14/56 min(0, -2147483648)--> 0, should be -2147483648
15/67 min(1, -2147483648)--> 1, should be -2147483648
16/68 min(1, -2147483647)--> 1, should be -2147483647
17/78 min(2, -2147483648)--> 2, should be -2147483648
18/79 min(2, -2147483647)--> 2, should be -2147483647
19/80 min(2, -2147483646)--> 2, should be -2147483646
20/89 min(2147483645, -2147483648)--> 2147483645, should be -2147483648
21/90 min(2147483645, -2147483647)--> 2147483645, should be -2147483647
22/91 min(2147483645, -2147483646)--> 2147483645, should be -2147483646
23/100 min(2147483646, -2147483648)--> 2147483646, should be -2147483648
24/101 min(2147483646, -2147483647)--> 2147483646, should be -2147483647
25/102 min(2147483646, -2147483646)--> 2147483646, should be -2147483646
26/103 min(2147483646, -2)--> 2147483646, should be -2
27/111 min(2147483647, -2147483648)--> 2147483647, should be -2147483648
28/112 min(2147483647, -2147483647)--> 2147483647, should be -2147483647
29/113 min(2147483647, -2147483646)--> 2147483647, should be -2147483646
30/114 min(2147483647, -2)--> 2147483647, should be -2
31/115 min(2147483647, -1)--> 2147483647, should be -1
```

Answer (score 4):

This part has the value `-1` if `x<y`, and `0` otherwise:

```
(x - y) >> (sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT - 1)
```

It accomplishes this by an arithmetic shift of 31 bits (or 63 if using 64-bit ints, etc). An arithmetic shift preserves the sign-bit, so for negative values you'll get a result where all bits are 1, and for positive values you'll get a result where all bits are 0. So for example, if `x=2` and `y=4`:

```
(2 - 4) >> (sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT - 1)
== (-2) >> (4 * 8 -1)
== (-2) >> 31
== 0xFFFFFFFE >> 31
== 0xFFFFFFFF 
== -1
```

This value is then used to mask `(x - y)`. That is, you'll get `(x - y) & -1 == (x - y)` if `x<y`, and `(x - y) & 0 == 0` otherwise.

Finally, that value is added to `y`, resulting in either `y + (x - y) == x`, or `y + 0 == y`.

Answer (score 4):

(For clarity we assume `sizeof(int) == 4` and `CHAR_BIT == 8`, but it works for any other sizes)

We parse it from the inner most expressions.

```
   (x - y) >> (sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT - 1)
== (x - y) >> 31
```

The `>>` for `int` is usually a sign-extended right shift (a.k.a. [arithmetic right shift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_shift)). Shifting by 31 bits leaves only the top-most bit, and then this bit is extended to the remaining 31 bits. This is actually equivalent to ⌊(x - y) / 2<sup>31</sup>⌋.

It should be not hard to see that `(x - y) >> 31` gives `-1` whenever `x - y` is negative, and `0` otherwise. So this is actually a fancy way to write

```
   x - y < 0 ? -1 : 0
== x < y ? -1 : 0
```

**Note that here we say `x - y < 0` is equivalent to `x < y`, but this only works when there is no overflow.** For instance, when `x == 0` and `y == INT_MIN`, `x - y` will overflow to `INT_MIN` which is negative, but `x < y` is certainly false.

Plug this back into the full expression:

```
   y + ((x - y) & ((x - y) >> (sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT - 1)))
== y + ((x - y) & (x < y ? -1 : 0))   // <- assume no overflow
```

When `x < y`, we get `(x - y) & -1`. Since `-1` has all bits set, so this is equivalent to `x - y`. When `x >= y`, we get `(x - y) & 0`, which is 0.

Therefore `((x - y) & (x < y ? -1 : 0))` is just a fancy way to write `x < y ? x - y : 0`.

```
== y + (x < y ? x - y : 0)
== x < y ? x : y
```

---

Because of the overflow bug, and that the expression is so tricky, you should never use this expression in practice. Just use `(x < y) ? x : y`.

Comment: It also worth noting in your closing paragraph, that most compilers can optimize the ternary operator as good as, or better than, most of the bit manipulation routines that purport to be an improvement anyway. It worth it for the OP to dump to assembly and check.

Comment: Using `>>` on negative values of signed types is implementation-defined. Sign-extension is only *one* possibility.