# Finding min and max between two numbers using bit manipulation in Go

Tags: go, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

What's the equivalent in Go syntax of the functions below:

```
/*Function to find minimum of x and y*/
public  static int min(int x, int y) { 
   return y ^ ((x ^ y) & -(x < y)); 
} 

/*Function to find maximum of x and y*/
public  static int max(int x, int y) { 
   return x ^ ((x ^ y) & -(x < y)); 
}
```

The part that I'm finding difficult to write is the negation of x less than y check. I have a version of the using the second suggestion in the article:

```
    min := y + ((x - y) & ((x - y) >> 31 ))
    max := x - ((x - y) & ((x - y) >> 31 ))
```

I want a bit-manipulation approach to avoid using branching.

source of the code from [http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#IntegerMinOrMax](http://graphics.stanford.edu/%7Eseander/bithacks.html#IntegerMinOrMax)

Note that this has been discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39195391/finding-minimum-using-bit-manipulation?rq=1) but not in the context of Go. It seems that the method has an undefined behavior for `x-y`.

Answer (score 3):

Because the expression `x < y` evaluates to a `bool` in Go, you will need to use an `if` statement to convert the result to `0` or `1`.  Otherwise, the operators in Go are the same as the operators in C++.

```
func Min(x, y int) int {
    var s int
    if x < y {
        s = -1
    }
    return y ^ ((x ^ y) & s)
}

func Max(x, y int) int {
    var s int
    if x < y {
        s = -1
    }
    return x ^ ((x ^ y) & s)
}
```

Comment: looks good. One part I want to avoid is the branching.

Comment: I added this to the question. That would be the main benefit of using bit manipulation, otherwise you could just have a direct comparison between x and y and return the min and max.

Comment: I thought this was a puzzler, not an optimization.  Write the obvious code and let the compiler handle the optimizations.

Answer (score 1):

Can it be done? Arguably yes, but turning a boolean into an int in a way that satisfies your criteria results in Weird Hacks, for example:

```
func convertBoolToInt(b bool) int {
    return *(*int)(unsafe.Pointer(&b)) & 1
}
```

This of course blatantly reads more bytes than were written to the address of `b`, the `& 1` gets rid of any "dirty bits" but it's definitely a hack.

Then this can be used around the comparisons to turn them into integers:

```
y ^ ((x ^ y) & -convertBoolToInt(x < y))
```

---

About `y + ((x - y) & ((x - y) >> 31 ))`, as the linked article notes, it has some limitation on the inputs. Actually it works for 75% of possible inputs.

In many cases that limitation is acceptable, because the inputs for which it breaks are far outside of the "typically used values". For when it is not acceptable, here is an alternative. The "comparison mask" (equivalent to `-(x < y)`) can be calculated as `((x - y) ^ ((x ^ y) & ((x - y) ^ x))) >> 31` (source: Hacker's Delight chapter 2, Basics). Plugging that into the first approach, we get:

```
func min(x int, y int) int { 
   return y ^ ((x ^ y) & (((x - y) ^ ((x ^ y) & ((x - y) ^ x))) >> 31))
}
```

The obvious downside being that it costs a lot more operations.